# Sending an xml array in service stack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am currently doing the following with ServiceStack to post some xml back to the server:

```
<Server xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <UserName>Bob</UserName>
    <UserGroups xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
       <d3p1:string>History</d3p1:string>
       <d3p1:string>Geography</d3p1:string>
     </UserGroups>
</Server>
```

The above works, however how do I do this as:

```
<Server xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <UserName>Bob</UserName>
    <UserGroups>
       <UserGroup>History</UserGroup>
       <UserGroup>Geography</UserGroup>
     </UserGroups>
</Server>
```

I have tried:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "UserGroup")]
public partial class ArrayOfStringUserGroup : List<string>
{
    public ArrayOfStringUserGroup()
    {
    }

    public ArrayOfStringUserGroup(IEnumerable<string> collection) : base(collection) { }
    public ArrayOfStringUserGroup(params string[] args) : base(args) { }
}
```

and my dto in the post has the following in:

```
  [DataMember(Name = "UserGroups", Order = 3)]
  public ArrayOfStringUserGroup UserGroups { get; set; }
```

But I get UserGroups as an empty array of UserGroupDto.

Answer (score 1):

This gives exactly what you want.

```
Server s = new Server();
s.UserName = "Bob";
s.UserGroups = new List<string>();
s.UserGroups.Add("History");
s.UserGroups.Add("Geography");


StringWriter stream = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter writer = 
            XmlTextWriter.Create(
              stream,
              new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true,Indent = true }
            );

XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Server));
xml.Serialize(writer,s,ns);

var xmlString = stream.ToString();
```

---

```
public class Server
{
    public string UserName;
    [XmlArrayItem("UserGroup")]
    public List<string> UserGroups;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am not clear how this works with servicestack? I will be sending json as well, not sure if the above will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to remove the redundant/repeated XML namespaces?

If so you should ensure all DTO types share the same single namespace which should match the `Config.WsdlServiceNamespace` if you want to change it from the default namespace: `http://schemas.servicestack.net/types`.

This can easily be done by using the `[assembly:ContractNamespace]` attribute usually defined in the DTO project's AssemblyInfo.cs file, here is how this is done in the ServiceStack.Examples project:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.servicestack.net/types",
           ClrNamespace = "ServiceStack.Examples.ServiceModel.Operations")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.servicestack.net/types",
           ClrNamespace = "ServiceStack.Examples.ServiceModel.Types")]
```

Taken from ServiceStack's [SOAP Support wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support).

Comment: Hi, I tried the above but did not work. Do I do this in addition to the ArrayOfStringUserGroup code I posted?. Both combinations did not work. Also, this is a REST based service where in the body of the POST I want to send the XML block without <d3p1:string> etc.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck, not sure why this is not working? Any examples of it working?